Image classification using annotated data
I have a variety of annotated images, that I am going to use in order to train my program to count the number of stitches from non annotated images.
Here is a Drive link with the resources: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dtFFr3dxIAoW6Ba3ae7TMWt_AbcggE6S?usp=sharing
import xmltodict
import csv
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import argparse

#Initialize the paths
xml_path = 'resources/annotations.xml'
csv_path = 'src/output.csv'

# Function to parse the XML and extract annotations
def parse_annotations(xml_path):
    with open(xml_path) as fd:
        doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
    annotations = []
    for image in doc["annotations"]["image"]:
        image_data = {'filename': image['@name'], 'stitches': []}
        if "polyline" in image:
            for pline in image["polyline"]:
                if isinstance(pline, dict) and '@label' in pline and pline['@label'] == 'Stitch':
                    points = [[float(p) for p in point.split(',')] for point in pline['@points'].split(';')]
                    image_data['stitches'].append(points)
        annotations.append(image_data)
    return annotations

# Initialize the annotations
annotations = parse_annotations(xml_path)

# Function to count stitches in an image based on annotations
def count_stitches(image_data):
    return len(image_data['stitches'])

# Update the annotations with the stitch count
for image_data in annotations:
    image_data['n_stitches'] = count_stitches(image_data)

def preprocess_image(image):
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Apply Gaussian blur (L%P)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    return blurred

def segment_image(gray_image):
    # Edge detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray_image, 50, 150)
    # Find contours
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    return contours

def visualize_contours(image, contours):
    vis_image = image.copy()
    cv2.drawContours(vis_image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv2.imshow('Contours', vis_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def count_detected_stitches(contours):
    # Simple heuristic for now: assume each contour is a stitch.
    # This will need to be replaced with a real classification model later.
    return len(contours)

def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Stitch Counter')
    parser.add_argument('output_csv', type=str, help='The CSV file to output results')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--visual', action='store_true', help='Visual mode to display images')
    parser.add_argument('images', type=str, nargs='+', help='Image filenames')
    return parser.parse_args()

#Function to write the results to a CSV file
def write_to_csv(results, csv_path):
    with open(csv_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(['filename', 'n_stitches'])
        writer.writerows(results)

def is_image_blurred(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    variance_of_laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()
    # If the variance is below a threshold, it's likely that the image is blurred.
    return variance_of_laplacian < 100  # The threshold may need adjustment.

def is_image_brightness_ok(image, threshold_low=50, threshold_high=200):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    brightness = np.mean(gray)
    # Check if the brightness is within the acceptable range
    return threshold_low < brightness < threshold_high

# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_arguments()
    annotations = parse_annotations(xml_path)

    # Create a dictionary from annotations for easy lookup
    annotation_dict = {image_data['filename']: image_data for image_data in annotations}

    # If the script is run with the `-v` visual flag or there are image arguments, use the provided images.
    # Otherwise, use the annotated images from the XML file.
    image_filenames = args.images if args.images or args.visual else [image_data['filename'] for image_data in annotations]

    results = []
    for filename in image_filenames:
        image_path = os.path.join('resources/incision_couples', filename)
        image = cv2.imread(image_path)

        if image is None:
            print(f"Error: Cannot read image {filename}.")
            results.append((filename, -1))
            continue
        elif not is_image_brightness_ok(image) or is_image_blurred(image):
            n_stitches = -1  # Image is either too bright/dark or too blurred
            print(f"Error: Cannot count stitches in image {filename}")
        else:
            if filename in annotation_dict:
                # Use the stitch count from the annotation
                n_stitches = annotation_dict[filename]['n_stitches']
            else:
                # Calculate the stitch count
                try:
                    if args.visual:
                        preprocessed_image = preprocess_image(image)
                        contours = segment_image(preprocessed_image)
                        visualize_contours(preprocessed_image, contours)
                        n_stitches = count_stitches(image_data)
                    else:
                        n_stitches = count_stitches(image_data)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error: Cannot count stitches in image {filename}")
                    n_stitches = -1

        results.append((filename, n_stitches))

    write_to_csv(results, args.output_csv)


For now, I am trying to count the number of stitches using the .xml file(which contains the annotations). For some reason I cannot do that properly. Could you please help me?

please clarify the issue. [mre]. do you have trouble reading an XML file, or not?
